# Search string and insert page break DOCX

Tags: python, docx

I need to search for strings in a DOCX document (with grep for example) and after finding it, insert a page break right after.

will it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

With docx, you can get the document texts into string.
Iterate over strings, then search the term you want for the `index`.

Insert the page break character (may be 0xC).